# React/Node app in Heroku, serving index.html/index.js with server running

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm pretty sure that this issue is localized to my start scripts. When looking online people will post differing start scripts.

Some have "start": "node index.js" -> (this won't start my server), gives an H10 error in heroku logs

Others have "start": "nodemon server.js" -> (this runs the server, serves the index.html, but it won't include the index.js file), no error given but not desired behavior

I used create-react-app, it works locally when i can do concurrent 'react-scripts start' and 'nodemon server', and my port is also set to the environment var.
let me know if I can provide extra info, and any help would be appreciated

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Server.js

```
require('dotenv').config();

var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var withAuth = require('./middleware');
const path = require('path');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 4090;

const { 
    receivePublicToken,
    getTransactions,
    getBalance,
    putCat,
    getCat,
    logIn,
    isUser
} = require("../src/controllers/controller");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// Get the public token and exchange it for an access token
app.post("/auth/public_token", withAuth, receivePublicToken);// Get Transactions
app.get("/transactions", getTransactions);
app.get("/accounts/balance/get", getBalance);
app.post("/users/login", logIn);
app.post("/categories/post", putCat);
app.get("/categories/get", getCat);
app.get("/auth", withAuth, isUser);
app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie('token').sendStatus(200);
})
app.get('*', (req, res) => { 
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html')) 
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`);
});
```

start script in package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"npm run start-client\"",
  "start-client": "react-scripts start"
  "start": "nodemon server/server.js",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "postinstall": "npm run build"
  }
```

[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Ong.jpg)

Comment: please share your index.js file

Comment: added, the index.html is the boilerplate template from create-react-app as well

Comment: you are then deploying it in wrong way

Comment: please share your project structure and node index.js file, not react index.js.

Comment: updated, i'm guessing node index.js file means my server.js file?

Answer (score 0):

I think your start script must be `node server/server.js`

Comment: It works locally but when i run it in heroku i get a blank page. When i add html to the index.html it shows up but it doesn't serve up the index.js with the html. I'm not sure if there is some way to make the javascript run with a react app index file..

Comment: this is a correct way of running it, only difference is, you don't have to change anything in index.html file in public folder inside react dir. If you html will not have `<div id="root"></div>` in your html then react won't render anything at all.

Comment: if you want to add any html, you will add into src/App.tsx file, not in html

Comment: index.html will only contain basic single div inside body and head, and nothing else, you will write your html and everything inside jsx files inside src

Comment: if you want to run a project locally, you need to run `npm run build` and then `npm run start`

Comment: right that makes sense, so how does the index.html know to use index.js locally and how can i make that happen in Heroku? Currently i'm thinking I need to adjust the scripts or i need to add a static file path in my server, looking into both those things now

Comment: in your react-app index.js this line `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));` is going to render your app inside div with id root

Comment: your index.html doesn't have to know anything or to do anything at all

Comment: yeah not sure why it won't call on the index.js in mine, especially since it works locally. going to read up a little more on heroku start scripts and maybe also look into the server as well

Answer (score 0):

Did you make a Procfile? If not, make a file named "Procfile" in your main directory, and add web: node Server.js to it. That should tell heroku what to do when it starts up.

Comment: I believe it is not necessary. If you look at his package.json, you will see his default command for serving the app is `start`. so no need to add Procfile

Comment: 90% of the time that works, but some of heoku's servers will not listen to the start command(its really annoying when it happens) and then will thow an internal error

Comment: i tried this and it didn't change the behavior at all so i went back on it, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Ok, cool. I assume you have this line, or something like it, but its the only thing that I can think of that might stop it from serving the index.js file :                                                           app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

Comment: this is something else I've been considering, I don't technically have a "client" folder but I have a public directory that houses the index.html, robot.txt, etc. and i have an index.js in my src directory which also houses my app.js, controller, etc.

Comment: so i used ```app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));``` and for the get request that heroku calls to start the app, i used ```app.get('*', (req, res) => { 
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')) 
});```

Comment: also to add, i posted a link to a picture at the bottom of my post, of my directory and you can see how the src and public directories are separate. which the index.html and index.js are split into one and the other.

Comment: Here is the express page for serving static files, https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html the last example might fix your problem